# Is a 3-D printed silencer feasible?

Tags: science-based, technology, weapons

Would it be feasible to construct a weapon silencer with modern day 3-D printers and available materials?

If so, what might the lifespan be? Is there any chance of creating a durable device or is it disposable at best?

Comment: Welcome to the site, fussmonkey, and thanks for reminding the intelligence community of our existence. ;)

Comment: @Frostfyre Considering how many different methods of destroying the world we have analyzed here... I think it is a safe bet that they are acutely aware of us. Probably infiltrated the site long ago.

Comment: Thanks @Frostfyre! And trust me, I thought a lot about that topic before posting. I see I'm in good company.

Comment: Do you only want to consider easy-to-access plastic printers or do you include those high-cost metal-printing machines?

Comment: Hello and welcome @fussmonkey to world building and world destruction :)

Since there are already documented cases of 3d printed weapons (cannot google it right now, because I'm at work) a 3d printed silencer is more than possible

Comment: @fussmonkey Don't be afraid to google! Silencers/suppressors/moderators are not illegal in the US, UK, or many other countries. They just require some paperwork.

Comment: The accepted answer covers the question of 3d printing silencers/suppressors quite well, but it's worth noting that unless your world absolutely _requires_ that the silencer be 3d-printed, extremely high-quality silencers could be made by almost any hobbyist (or better) machinist with a drill and a lathe. Search "Form 1 silencer" for information about how this is (legally) done in the US.

Comment: Thanks, @Deolater. I feel a lot better about diving into researching the topic in more depth.

Comment: @Deolater: Why bother with 3D printing?  I'm told that a reasonably effective silencer can be created from a 1-liter plastic soda bottle and some duct tape.

Comment: I would probably go with printing a mold in 3d, then molding the piece in better materials (see John Malkovitch in "in the line of fire")

Comment: @jamesqf In the US any portable device that reduces the report of a firearm is technically a silencer under the National Firearms Act and illegal to own without approved forms. This would supposedly even include the plastic bottle or whatever. That said, judging by Youtube videos, a pillow or large stuffed animal works better than a bottle. Not only does it seem to be quieter, but you can also reposition the gun's muzzle and get multiple shots. A more conventional silencer can be made pretty easily in a simple machine shop and has the advantage of being much more reusable. Though less deniable

Comment: To be extra pedant: no, it is not possible, with or without 3d printing to make a true silencer like what you see in movies and video games. Suppressors exist, but they don't make the gunshot a noiseless little sigh, you will still wake up the neighbors just like as if you had hit their wall with a hammer.

Comment: Are you interested in silencer for already-existing weapon (which usually assumes metal silencer) or can we design a weapon too, e.g. with holes in a barrel like [here](http://huntsmanblog.ru/vintovka-snajperskaya-specialnaya-vss-vintorez/)?

Comment: @Deolater: Ah, but the beauty of the plastic bottle is that it isn't a silencer until you use it as one.  "Silencer?  What silencer?  I'm just taking these bottles to recycling."

Comment: @Daerdemandt, I was envisioning an existing weapon when I asked the question. But at this point I'm really enjoying the conversation and I'd be happy to see where you went with that. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes, it is feasible to construct a silencer

Here are a [pair](https://3dprint.com/52245/3d-printed-plastic-silencer/) of [3-d printed](https://3dprint.com/56493/metal-3d-printed-gun-silencer/) silencers. The first is plastic, the second is metal.

## Yes, you can take a durable device, but the work is in progress

First off, it is feasible to make an [AR-15 lower receiver](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/03/download-this-gun-3d-printed-semi-automatic-fires-over-600-rounds/) in a 3-d printer that lasts around 1,000 rounds. That isn't great, but the lower receiver is the part that takes the brunt of the explosion force of the cartridge. Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_printed_weapons_and_parts) of various 3-d printed gun parts.

A silencer doesn't take the mechanical stresses that a lower receiver does, but will be subject to plenty of heat. The plastic silencer is pretty much a one or two shot deal before it starts to melt from heat. The metal one, though, with some engineering should be able to last at least as long as a lower receiver.

Its worth keeping in mind, that this is very much a brand new technology. As you can see by the spacing on those articles, these 3-d printed weapons have only been viable in the last couple years. I would expect significant improvements in the near future as more try-and-fail experimentation is carried out.

Comment: Thanks for the variety of links. I wasn't really sure how to dive into researching this (see my comment on the OP). Feels scary to type certain keywords into a search box.

Comment: @fussmonkey Don't be cowed by the anti-gun people! The internet is the great wild west of the anti-government gun movement. The best thing is, you don't have to worry about big brother keeping an eye on you if you have enough guns!

Comment: One nitpick: The lower receiver of an AR-15 doesn't really deal with a lot of mechanical stress except right at the receiver extension/buffer tube. However, a silencer DOES experience a lot of mechanical stress. The silencer really, really wants to blow downrange, and must be securely attacked or bad things happen.

Comment: I wish I could edit comments. There is no need to "attack" the silencer, "attaching" it suffices.

Comment: It might be possible to add a metal sleeve of some type inside the barrel of the plastic version to help witht the heat issues, and make it last a little longer.

Comment: @Mr.Durden There are all metal silencers, like in the second link in my answer.

Comment: @kingledion Yes i saw the link, I was just mentioning a possible easy add on to the plastic version for someone who only had that type of 3D printer.

Comment: @Deolater Yes, from my understanding for a suppressor to operate properly it needs to capture and redirect the expanding gases behind the bullet without letting the gases escape *around* the bullet (letting noise escape) essentially making it an extension of the barrel and requiring similar tolerances to the polished ramps for the bullet on the inside of the barrel. If this is true, for a repeat-use suppressor it might be dealing more mechanical stresses than we are anticipating, at best shortening its lifespan considerably. Professional suppressors go for $ 300-600, so what do you really gain

Comment: @ITBear You gain by making them yourself, Hillary can't take away your suppressors! Wait a minute...

Comment: @kingledion Even if Hillary had power, our biggest asset is that most overreacting no-gun-dems aren't even aware that suppressors are legal to purchase with a tax stamp. Heck, even my friends with guns get confused about this ammo/armor/full-auto stuff at times, debate about it. But when the big overreaction backlash comes it's usually focused on "assault weapons" and "registration", so I'd rather just have [this](https://www.gunsamerica.com/blog/ghost-gunner-making-ars-home-never-easy/). For the rest just *shhh, keep quiet and maybe they won't notice all the other laws while on their crusade*

Comment: @IT Bear, usually the hole through the baffles is a bit larger than the bore diameter to avoid baffle strikes. While theoretically smaller is better, it seems to matter less in practice. That said, many older designs use wipes, where the bullet makes its own hole, rather than baffles.

Answer (score 14):

## Metal 3D printing

Since you can do [3D printing in metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_metal_laser_sintering), the short answer is: yes, you can make a firearms **suppressor** (pet peeve: you cannot make a gun be **silent**, only **suppressed**) with a metal 3D printer.

There may some issue about how well a 3D printer can do the threads for the suppressor, but that is nothing that cannot be solved by having a fixed threader available for polishing up.

As for a **plastic** 3D printed suppressor... well, that is probably **possible** but unless you want it to fly apart on the first shot it probably needs to be made quite thick and sturdy.

Comment: Point taken regarding the accuracy of the term "suppressor" and I'll use that going forward.

Comment: @fussmonkey Don't worry about silencer vs suppressor. The inventor called the "silencers". Personally I prefer the word "firearm muffler", but I use "silenpressor" online just to make sure nobody is happy.

Comment: The ultimate field expedient "suppressor" is a 2l plastic pop (soda) bottle fitted over the muzzle to suppress one shot. It won't melt from the shot, but the large hole in the end after you shoot makes it less useful afterwards.

Comment: @Deolater For worldbuilding purposes, the distinction is important if OP is going for realism. Real silencers are nothing like the movies, and don't guarantee an undetectable noise.

Comment: @SethWhite I absolutely agree that the actual noise level does matter for realism, but the terminology isn't terribly important. "Silencer", "suppressor" and (UK) "moderator" are all names with varying degrees of descriptiveness, and all are used by people with direct experience. Both of my "cans" are made by companies that call them "silencers". My comment was not an attempt to claim that the term "silencer" is fully descriptive, just that "silencer" is a perfectly legitimate word for the things and would not be out of place in a work of fiction.

Comment: @SethWhite ... as long as the muffled gunshots are not presented as sounding like a puff of air. I don't know where hollywood got that idea.

Comment: @Deolater Not to mention the laser gun sound effect often used.

Comment: I'm not too sure that a half a million dollar 3D printer is "feasible" ;)

Comment: Note that you can print in PLA and then use it in place of wax for casting metal, and it’s easy to cast aluminium at home.

Answer (score 0):

People talking about metal and plastic printers, but what about resin ones?
Well, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekDs60QxmNE) you can see an AMAZING person do it, and it works really well.
Can't say much about durabillity tough, it is a really new field.
But the cool thing is resin printers are pricier than plastic ones, but WAY WAY WAY cheaper than metal ones. And everyone with a bit of engeneering and much magverism can do it in your backyard, so if you need to your characters do a makeshift silenpressor (i loved the term my dear Deolater) is the best choice.